# PowerBI Dax for point in time Calculation - TimeSeries

Tags: dax

I am trying to find a solution to get number of students in a course at selected point of time.
the student has a status of either enrolled and passed. I have a table (say tblClass) with studentid, EnrollDate, PassedDate.
I created a new date table (say tblDate) with 1 column 'Date' and mapped it to EnrollDate in tblClass.

If the person has passed the course, the 'passeddate' column will have some date value.
if the person is still enrolled, the 'passeddate' field will be blank.
first 30 days are trial period so, do not count the person as student unless he/she takes exam and passes the course.

If we are calculating student head count as of today the DAX would be like
check if the passed date is populated or not. if populated then flag it as a student
check if the passed date is blank. check the datediff between enrolled date and today. if greater than 30 days then count as student else not.

when I introduce time travel feature into it, I am not able to get student head count dynamically for a selected date from the past.

Example:
Todays date is  March 25th

Scenario 1#
say a person enrolled on Feb 1st and passed the course on March 5th.

when I try   finding the head count on Feb 28th, point in time, the person should NOT be counted as student as it has been less than 30 days.
when I try finding the status on Mar 3rd, point in time, the person should be counted as student.

Scenario 2#
Say a person enrolled on Feb 1st and passed on Feb 4th.
When I try to get head count on feb 3rd, the person should NOT counted as student.
When I try to get head count on Feb 4th, the person should be counted as student

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

I tried capturing the selected date in DAX and
Use it to find whether the passed date is less than or more than selected date
if the selected date is greater than passed date then counted towards student head count
if the selected date is less than Passed date then checked if datediff between enrolldate and selected date is greater than 30 or not. Combining these scenarios in DAX is giving me only for selected month but not for prior months. I tried to remove filter by using ALL in the CALCULATE function but that did not resolve it.

here is the DAX

```
DynDSE_Active = /*Days Since the person is enrolled to selected date*/ 
var seldate= if(selectedvalue(tblDate[MonthEndDate])>=TODAY(),TODAY(), selectedvalue(tblDate[MonthEndDate])) 
VAR dayssinceEnrolled= CALCULATE(DATEDIFF(VALUES(tblClass[EnrollDate]),seldate,DAY), REMOVEFILTERs('tblClass'[EnrollDate])) 
RETURN dayssinceEnrolled
```

Comment: Share your code and errors logs (if any)

Comment: I tried taking one step a time and did not include all the constraints for my initial effort. Below code works to get todays days since enrolled. if no date selection is made, it populates correct values. If I select a prior month, the results are restricted to selected month. REMOVE FILTERS within CALCULATE function did not actually get applied.

Comment: here is the DAX 
DynDSE_Active = /*Days Since the person is enrolled to selected date*/
var seldate= if(selectedvalue(tblDate[MonthEndDate])>=TODAY(),TODAY(), selectedvalue(tblDate[MonthEndDate]))

VAR dayssinceEnrolled=
            CALCULATE(DATEDIFF(VALUES(tblClass[EnrollDate]),seldate,DAY),                                 REMOVEFILTERs('tblClass'[EnrollDate]))
RETURN dayssinceEnrolled